# cannot understand the use of split in java

Tags: java

my code is:-

```
class SplitString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p;
        String test = "a1b2c3";
        String[] token1 = test.split("\\d");
        System.out.println("first case : " + token1.length);

        for (String s : token1)
            System.out.print(s + " ");

        String[] token2 = test.split("\\b");
        System.out.println("\n\nsecond case : " + token2.length);

        for (String s : token2)
            System.out.print(s + " ");

        String[] token3 = test.split("\\a");
        System.out.println("\n\nthird case : " + token3.length);

        for (String s : token3)
            System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
first case : 3
a b c

second case : 2
 a1b2c3

third case : 1
a1b2c3
```

I am new to java and trying to execute split but cannot able to grasp its concept since all cases have different answers but what exactly the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` method, as you may know, uses a regex pattern to split the string:

- first case `\d` splits it using number digits as delimiters
- second case `\b` splits it using word boundaries, so you actually have an empty string and the whole remainder
- third case `\a` is a special character, which is not present in the string you are splitting, so you just have one token

Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for all the regex options.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is right there in the Javadoc. `split` interprets the string you give it as a **regular expression**, not a literal string. Please find the full details on the regular expression syntax [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Or, if you are using Eclipse, you can play with regular expressions using Eclipse's Find dialog box (check the "Regular expression" checkbox).

Comment: ya i got it...but can u xplain me that difference between \\b(word boundary) and \\B(non-word boundary)

Comment: This is also a good point to note.  In your first case, for example, "d" represents "digit" in regular expressions, so that's why you only ended up with "a b c".

Comment: What explanation do you need, Himanshu? Did you google for "java regex word boundary"? [This is the first hit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Answer (score 1):

Split will break up a string into an array of string using a common delimiter.  A more common example is if your data were comma-seperated like so:

1,2,3,4,5

then, if you split your data on the comma character, you'd end up with an array of 5 strings:
["1","2","3","4","5"]

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the separator `\d` represents any digit. The string is broken apart at each group of digits.

In the second case, `\b` represents a word boundary. The beginning of the string counts, so the string is split there.

In the third case, `\a` represents the character BEL (ASCII 7). There is no such character in the string, so the string is not split.

A complete guide to the expression syntax is found [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

See [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
\d  A digit: [0-9]
\a  The alert (bell) character ('\u0007')
\b  A word boundary
```

So first case -  split numbers, second "a word", third all string - bell character does not found